# What if axios call in getServerSideProps() failed? How to repeat

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I'm trying to pre render page using getServerSideProps in Next.js and everything works perfectly.
But what if the axios call failed due to server issue or Network error?
How can I repeat the call?

Here's my code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  let ImagesList = {};

  await axios
    .get("https://www.*****.com/api/home")
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data) {
        ImagesList = response.data

      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { });

  return {
    props: {
      ImagesList,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do so in the catch ... conditionally (i.e. only when appropriate) `return getServerSideProps()`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to retry 5xx requests using axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074531/how-to-retry-5xx-requests-using-axios)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to wrap your axios call inside a while loop,

```js
let result = false;

while(!result) {
await axios
    .get("https://www.*****.com/api/home")
    .then((response) => {
      result = true
      if (response.data) {
        ImagesList = response.data

      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { });
}
```